# How to automatizate json calls?

Tags: android, json, loops, callback

I want to get JSON data from 27 different urls, I'm adding always +1 per page to the url, the problem is that the call is slower then the loop so the loop always initializate my JSON class, and it startes always again so it never finishes.

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            page = 1;
            final boolean[] first = {true};
            while (page <= 27) {
                if (first[0] == true) {
                    jsonData = new JSON("http://1956.osaarchivum.org/api/items?collection=13&page=" + page + "&per_page=50", SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity.this);
                    jsonData.mJSONInterface = new JSONInterface() {
                        @Override
                        public void startActivityJSON() {
                            Log.v("INNERTAG", "SUCCESSFUL CALL");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.getCollections().length; i++) {
                                Log.v("Current I:", i + "");
                                final JSONMedia jsonMedia = new JSONMedia(jsonData.getCollections()[i].getMediaURL(), SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity.this);
                                final int finalI = i;
                                jsonMedia.mJSONMediaInterface = new JSONInterface() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void startActivityJSON() {
                                        jsonData.getCollections()[finalI].setMediaURL(jsonMedia.getMediaUrl());
                                        mCollectionList.add(jsonData.getCollections()[finalI]);
                                        Log.v("NEWMEDIA", jsonMedia.getMediaUrl());
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                            page++;
                            first[0] = true;
                        }
                    };
                    first[0] = false;
                }

                Log.v("TAH", "END OF LOOP");
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried it with a a boolean first variable to stop the initialization, but suddenly it doesn't work.
The inner for loop changes just the MediaURL of the collection, but it worked just with 1 page.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-automate-Rest-Api-service-calls-to-Check-for-Json-security-Tokens-in-request-response-headers

Comment: Isn't ther any easier ways to get this done?